# Give an example of a function $f$ with an essential discontinuity everywhere and yet $(f)^2$ is continuous everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

### Note: $(f)^2$ means $(f \circ f)$. That is to say, $f$ composed with itself

---

To begin this problem, I consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

For $x \neq 0, f(x)$ is defined

But at $x=0,$ $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ has an essential discontinuity since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}$ does not exist.

Notice however that $(f)^2=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=x$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} x=0$

---

This example works when $f$ is disontinuous at a point. How do I construct a function that is discontinuous for **all values** whose composition with itself is continuous for **all values**?

Comment: $(f)^2=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=x$ doesn't make sense, but $(f)^2 = \frac{1}{x^2}$ does.

Comment: With the book I'm using, I just assumed that $(f)^2$ meant $(f \cdot f)$. That is to say, $f$ composed with itself. Is that not what is meant by $(f)^2$?

Comment: then you should state it clearly that $(f)^2 = f(f)$.

Comment: Okay I will fix it

Comment: Are you sure that $\cdot$ doesn't mean pointwise multiplication? Function composition is rather denoted by $\circ$ `\circ`.

Comment: We're getting away from the point here. The question is asking about function composition. I'll change it to a circle but we're quibbling over details here. The intention is function composition.

Comment: What about $f(x) = 1_\Bbb{Q}(x)$?

Comment: @PhoemueX I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that notation. What is $1_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)?$

Comment: It's the characteristic function of $\Bbb Q$. For $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ we have $1_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $=0$ if $x\notin A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick your favorite dense subset $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ containing $0$ and $1$, such that its complement, $A^C$, is dense as well. Then $1_A$ is discontinuous everywhere and $1_A\circ 1_A$ is just constantly $1$.

($1_A$ is the function which is $1$ on $A$ and $0$ on $A^C$).

Comment: Excellent! ( comment too short)

Comment: This answer is perfect, it works wonderfully. But I must ask, why must $0$ and $1 \in A$? The characteristic function composed with itself suffices for this question regardless of whether $0$ or $1 \in A$

Answer (score 1):

How's about $f(x)= x(-1)^{ \mathbb{1}_{x \in \mathbb{Q}}}$

Comment: almost.  But this is continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Hm, but in the title, it requests only essential discontinuity.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen is correct. Essential discontinuity is all that is required. I'm having trouble reading your function. Did you mean $f(x)=x(-1)^1$ and $x \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @ManCheese my function $f(x)=-x$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=x$ if x is irrational.